# Thermodynamic partial derivatives

Tags: math-mode

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this:

[image]

look like this:

[image]

The only difference is the differentials are "pushed over" making it appear more compact and readable.  I achieved the first picture by using

```
\left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right|_{V,N} \mathrm{d} S
```

(first term only) but I don't know how to push the dS over the subscript more.  Can this even be done?

I've tried `\overset` and using a custom fraction but neither look quite right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You can insert negative math spaces such as `\!` before `dS`

Answer (score 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right|_{\mathrlap{V,N}} \mathrm{d} S
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: is it good practice to use mathtools instead of ams bunch ?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!  Thank-you!

Comment: @texenthusiast: it loads `amsmath` by default _and_ fixes some bugs

Comment: @Herbert, what kind of bugs?

Comment: @Sigur: read the documentation